# Loop html checkbox in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

Actually i have a question regarding how to loop check boxes in java script, say i have created html checkbox in a jsp loop, i wish to do validation for those checkbox in javascript, how  should i do that? 
Normally for single object we can do like window.document.form.checkbox or something similar.

```
<%   
    for(int i=1; i<somevalue; i++)    //jsp 
    {
%>
    <input type="checkbox"  name="chkbox_"<%=i> value="<%=something%>">   <!-- html -->
<%
    }
%>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to me, we have some solutions:

## 1:

If you don't want to modify HTML code and using Javascript. You can use this method `getElementsByTagName`. Example http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_getelementsbytagname.asp, http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementsbytagname.asp

```
var checkboxes = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
    if (checkboxes[i].type == "checkbox") {
        var isChecked = checkboxes[i].checked;
    }
}
```

## 2:

Add `class` attribute for all checkbox and use this method `getElementsByClassName`

## 3:

Add `id` attribute for each checkbox and use `getElementById` method

## 4:

Use JQuery

```
$("input[type=='checkbox']").each(obj, function(key, value) {
    //  Do something
});
```

Comment: thanks for the help, instead of getting the object id, can i get it with object's name?

Comment: Yep, you can use object's name but I think our code performance is not good. Assumption, we have 10 `input` elements (checkboxes), we will need to loop each of 10 elements and check their name. So, why we don't use `class` or JQuery