# loop over checkbox and add the value to the new attribute

Tags: javascript

I am doing a loop over checkboxes and wanted to add the attribute aria-label to it and the value of it from my child span tag

i am following this code

[Loop html checkbox in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27194121/loop-html-checkbox-in-javascript)

but my html loops like this

```
<div role="group" aria-label="checkbox-group" class="checkbox-group transfer-panel__list">
    <label class="checkbox transfer-panel__item">
        <span class="checkbox__input">
            <span class="checkbox__inner"></span>
            <input type="checkbox" aria-hidden="false" class="checkbox__original" value="3">
        </span>
        <span class="checkbox__label">
            <span>Account number</span>
        </span>
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox transfer-panel__item">
        <span class="checkbox__input">
            <span class="checkbox__inner"></span>
            <input type="checkbox" aria-hidden="false" class="checkbox__original" value="4">
        </span>
        <span class="checkbox__label">
            <span>Status</span>
        </span>
    </label>
</div>
```

how i want my code to look after the change i am trying only in **javascript**, ***no jquery***

```
<div role="group" aria-label="checkbox-group" class="checkbox-group transfer-panel__list">
    <label class="checkbox transfer-panel__item">
        <span class="checkbox__input">
            <span class="checkbox__inner"></span>
            <input type="checkbox" aria-hidden="false" class="checkbox__original" value="3" aria-label="Account Number">
        </span>
        <span class="checkbox__label">
            <span>Account number</span>
        </span>
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox transfer-panel__item">
        <span class="checkbox__input">
            <span class="checkbox__inner"></span>
            <input type="checkbox" aria-hidden="false" class="checkbox__original" value="4" aria-label="Status">
        </span>
        <span class="checkbox__label">
            <span>Status</span>
        </span>
    </label>
</div>
```

tried something like this, which does work but i am not sure how to get the value of the span element

```
var container = document.querySelector('.transfer-panel__list');
var checkboxesAll = container.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
var _nextSibling = container.querySelector('.checkbox__label');
for (var i = 0; i < checkboxesAll.length; i++) {
    if (checkboxesAll[i].type == "checkbox") {
        checkboxesAll[i].setAttribute('aria-label','100');
        console.log(checkboxesAll[i]);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: If you don't want a jQuery solution, please don't add the jQuery tag to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this would work:

```
var container = document.querySelector('.transfer-panel__list');
var panelItemsAll = container.querySelectorAll('.transfer-panel__item');

for (var i = 0; i < panelItemsAll.length; i++) {
    panelItem = panelItemsAll[i];
    checkbox = panelItem.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"]');
  
    if (checkbox) {
        let labelValue = panelItem.querySelector('.checkbox__label span').innerText;
        checkbox.setAttribute('aria-label', labelValue);
    }
}
```

You can start iterating from `transfer-panel__item` elements, so you can query both checkbox and the label span in the context of an item.